# WPF MVVM-Light how to use the passed DragEventArgs in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, event-handling, mvvm-light

I have read many questions and answers about WPF MVVM Light here, but the answers show mostly only one side (the XAML code see below) and there is no the ViewModel code at all.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">
    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=DropCommand}"
                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
</i:EventTrigger>
```

I use in XAML Grid-Control and I want to apply Drag&Drop files from windows explorer to my (wpf) application. I strictly use MVVM pattern (avoid the code behind completely).
JFYI, in code-behind usually the event handler of Drop-Event has 2 parameters: sender of type object and e of type DragEventArgs. I just need the EventArgs.
My question is NOT about how to pass DragEventArgs from XAML directly to ViewModel anymore, but how to get and use the DragEventArgs in ViewModel (c# code). In ViewModel I write the Command like this:

```
public RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> DropCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _dropCommand ?? (_dropCommand = new RelayCommand<DragEventArgs>(Drop);
    }
}
private void Drop()
{
   // do something here
}
```

I think I miss something in my DropCommand, so I can use the e (type of DragEventArgs).
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something like:

What your missing is in your function definition to specify the argument type your expecting :)

```
private RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> _dropCommand;
public RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> DropCommand {
  get {
    return _dropCommand ?? (_dropCommand = new RelayCommand<DragEventArgs>(Drop));
  }
}
private static void Drop(DragEventArgs e) {
  // do something here
}
```

Or in a lamda'ish way (I do like my lamda's):

```
public RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> DragCommand { get; private set; }

public MainViewModel() {
  DragCommand = new RelayCommand<DragEventArgs>((e) =>  /* Handler Code */ , (e) => true);
}
```